# Recipe compile error - Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have 2 recipes in my cookbook namely - `Get.rb` and `Post.rb`.

`Get.rb` creates one file `app.conf` which is ultimately gets open in `Post.rb`.

So `Post.rb` depends on `Get.rb`, hence in my run-list I have placed `Get.rb` first and then `Post.rb`.

When I run chef-client, I am getting recipe compile error because the file `app.conf` is not present.

Looks like chef compiles both recipes simultaneously. 
What is the way to solve this?

Edit : 
 I have come this far:

```
ruby_block 'run' do 
     action :nothing 
     file = ::File.read('/etc/test.conf') 
     data = JSON.parse(file) unless file.nil? 
     puts data 
     only_if { File.exist?('/etc/test.conf') } 
end
```

I am still getting the error. What could be the issue in this block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for a full explanation but basically you want to rework your code using the lazy helper or create a custom resource.

Comment: I went through the link you gave. But I basically want to compile `Post.rb` after `Get.rb`. Can we do it using `lazy` ? According to my understanding we can only use `lazy` for resources.

Comment: Like I said, you need to rework all code in `Post.rb` that is using the file data. You cannot fix it at the recipe level.

Comment: Ok. I rewrote the code according to the link you had given. Still getting the error. Could you please see the edit in the question? I have mentioned the resource block there. Thanks.

Comment: It is highly unlikely a ruby_block resource is what you want but you haven't said any specifics beyond that one bit so I can't say anything more certain.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with some editing:

```
ruby_block 'run' do 
   action :run
   block do 
      file = ::File.read('/etc/test.conf') 
      data = JSON.parse(file) unless file.nil? 
      puts data 
   end
   only_if { File.exist?('/etc/test.conf') } 
end
```